# How to hide blackberry cursor in browser?

Tags: javascript, css, blackberry, cursor

Is it possible to hide the blackberry cursor in the browser? Using Javascript or CSS?

I am trying to rebuild the technique used on native apps where you browse through the items with your poke. I think this works nice on their native apps and I like to use that technique on my website where visitors can browse through various of items using their blackberry poke.

PS. CSS

```
* {
    cursor: url(cursor.png), none !important;
}
```

Does not work.

Comment: Why do you want to hide my cursor? :)

Comment: errrrr, why would you want to do this?

Comment: Maybe he wants a more native BB looking "app". (Web page.) ;-)

Comment: what about non-touch BB devices?

Answer (score 0):

[This BlackBerry page](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11849/CSSStyleDeclaration_568452_11.jsp) seems to confirm the cursor style can be changed.

What is the cursor.png file that you are using?  Have you tried changing the PNG to be a completely transparent file instead of specifying "none" in the CSS?  [This website](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-156101.html) seems to suggest that will work.

As per the comment you should consider what happens for non touch screen devices, but you can always choose to target only touch screen devices by specifying the device models in App World when you deploy your app.